# auto updating gps position in app creating a list

Tags: android, kotlin, gps

I am working on an app in Kotlin / Android Studio which is updating the gps position every 60 minutes or change of some miles between positions and it is working, however I cannot get it to give me the positions in a list view.
For example #1 date time Lat Long, #2 time Last Long...

```
var counter = 1 
button.setOnClickListener {
        this.getLocation()
        val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM hh-mm a")
        val dateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.time)
        val time = dateTime.toString()
        // rumbo etRumbo and velocidad barco etVb
        val outputRumbo1 = outputRumbo1Text.text.toString()
        val messageRumbo1 = "RA$outputRumbo1"
        rumboText1.text = messageRumbo1
        val outputVb1 = outputVb1Text.text.toString()
        val messageVb1 = "Vm $outputVb1 kn"
        velocidadMaquinaText1.text = messageVb1
        val outputWaveHeight2 = waveHeight2.text.toString()
        val message2 = "$outputWaveHeight2 m"
        waveText2.text = message2
        val outputWind2 = windSpeed2.text.toString()
        val messageWind2 = "$outputWind2 kn"
        outputWind2Text.text =  messageWind2
        val outputRA2 = tvRA2.text.toString()
        val messageRA2 = "$outputRA2"
        tvRA2.text = messageRA2
        //val latTest : Int =(location.latitude).toInt()
        //val text2 = ((latTest.toString()) + "°"+(latSum3.toString()) + "'N  " +   ((longTest.toString())+"°"+(longSum3.toString()) + "'E"))
        // generate a new line of text
        val newText = "$counter .$dateTime GPS position $messageRumbo1° $messageVb1 \n Wind: $messageWind2 Waves: $message2"
        // append the new text to the existing text in the TextView
        textView.append("\n$newText" )
        counter++
        //textView5.text = dateTime
        //  tvLogTime.text =dateTime
        tvLogTime2.text =dateTime
        tvLogTime.text =dateTime
    }
    }
    private fun getLocation() {
    locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), locationPermissionCode)
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 600, 2f, this)
    // locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1900000(=31,666666 min), 5f, this)
    // 600000ms = 10min 3600000ms = 1hour
}
override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
    tvGpsLocation = findViewById(R.id.tvLatFooter)
    tvGpsLocation.text = "Latitude: " + (location.latitude)  + "\nLongitude: "+ (location.longitude)
    val tv5 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv5)
    val tv6 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv6)
    val tv7 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv7)
    val tv8 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv8)
    val tv9 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv9)
    val latTest : Int =(location.latitude).toInt()
    val latTestDec : Float =(location.latitude).toFloat()
    val latSum = latTestDec - latTest
    var latSum2 = latSum * 60
    var latSum3 = ("%.1f".format(latSum2)  )
    val longTest : Int =(location.longitude).toInt()
    val longTestDec : Float =(location.longitude).toFloat()
    val longSum = longTestDec - longTest
    var longSum2 = longSum * 60
    var longSum3 = ("%.1f".format(longSum2)  )
    tv5.text = (latTest.toString())
    tv6.text = "°"+(latSum3.toString()) + "'N"
    tv7.text = (longTest.toString())
    tv8.text =  "°"+(longSum3.toString()) + "'E"
    tv9.text = (latTestDec.toString()) + "°North"
    var tvLogLat2: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tvLogLat2)
    // val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
    val text = ((latTest.toString()) + "°"+(latSum3.toString()) + "'N  " + ((longTest.toString())+"°"+(longSum3.toString()) + "'E"))
    tvLogLat2.text = text
    val tvLatFooter: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tvLatFooter)
    val tvLongFooter: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tvLongFooter)
    tvLatFooter.text =  ((latTest.toString()) + "°"+(latSum3.toString()) + "'N" )
    tvLongFooter.text = ((longTest.toString()) + "°"+(longSum3.toString()) + "'E")
}
```

The button is asking for the gPS location and it will give me a list view of several inputs but the GPS position is defined in function getLocation and I don't know how to merge the 2 areas.
Tried several things but not getting anywhere.
Would appreciate help with this.